# Calculate the complex integral $ \int _\gamma{\operatorname{Re}(\xi)d\xi}$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Compute $$ \int _\gamma{\operatorname{Re}(\xi)d\xi},$$
where $\gamma(t)$ is the right semicircle with radius $1$ and center $0$ from $z=-i$ to $z=i$.

$$z_0=0,\,\, R=1,\,\,z=[-i,i]$$
I tried this.

$$z(t)=x(t)+iy(t)=\cos(t) + i \sin(t)$$
$$ \xi(t)=\cos(t) + i \sin(t)\to \operatorname{Re}(\xi)=\cos(t)$$
$$ \xi'=-\sin (t)+i\cos(t) $$

$$ \int _\gamma{\operatorname{Re}(\xi)d\xi}=\int _{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\cos(t)(-\sin (t)+i\cos(t))} dt$$

I don't know if it's a correct procedure and how to evaluate the integral.

Comment: I think you're on the right track so far: what are the bounds on $t$ for your parametrization?

Comment: The last integral should no longer be on $\gamma$ but on a suitable real interval.

Comment: Is the interval $0$ to $\pi$ ? I got confused with that.

Comment: @qw.15125 What are the phases of $i$ and $-i$? How does the phase change as you move from $-i$ to $i$ along the circular arc?

Comment: I determine that is $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$ because is a semicircle of -i to i, is it correct?

Comment: @qw.15125 Yes, you are right.